# PHP HTTP request to localhost dead-locks

Tags: php, apache, http

in PHP im trying to spawn a cronjob by doing a request to localhost.
But on a specific LAMP (Ubuntu 14.04, mod_php) server the request timesout and is not handle at all by PHP. Requests to static files work.

This **works**:
`<?php echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/static-file.txt'); ?>`

This **times out**:
`<?php echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/cron.php'); ?>`

I tried to call `session_write_close();` before doing the request, but this does not help either.

What can prevent PHP from "spawning" itself?

Comment: this seems like an infinite loop. you're saying that `cron.php` is trying to get itself with the line `file_get_contents('http://localhost/cron.php')`?

Comment: No, there are 2 individual scripts. There is no inifinte loop.